# Reduce an Array down to its non-unique elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I'm trying to create a function which receives an Array and returns a new Array without unique elements, example:

```
nonUniqueElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])
// Result: [1, 3, 1, 3]
```

I tried to do it with two `for` loops without success.

Comment: Show us some code!

Comment: Also, what's your question?

Comment: Why use *for* loops when you could use *filter* or *reduce*?

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Show the code you have tried that isn't working as expected and people help you fix ***your code***.  That's how this site works

Comment: I think  he want to  remove items which are non duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to filter the elements that are not unique. If one of these two `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` returned an index diferent from the index of the current element, then it's not unique. **NOTE** that `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` can't return `-1` since there is at least one element equal to the current one in the array.

```js
var arr = [1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3];

var result = arr.filter(function(e, i){
  return arr.indexOf(e) != arr.lastIndexOf(e);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: or even `return arr.indexOf(e) !== arr.lastIndexOf(e) ;`

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it with 2 loops then something like this ?

```
var test = [1, 2, 'A', 3, 'C', 1, 'A', 3, 'D', 'A'];
var result = count_occurrences_limit(test, 1);

function count_occurrences_limit(arr, limit) {
    var objs_count = {};
    for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
        objs_count [arr[i]] = (objs_count [arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
    }
    var final_reduced = [];
    for (vari in objs_count) {
        if (objs_count[vari] > limit) {
            final_reduced[vari] = objs_count[vari];
        }
    }
    return final_reduced;
}

/*[1: 2, 3: 2, A: 3]*/
```